# Loop Stored Procedure in VB.Net (win form)

Tags: sql, vb.net, winforms, backup, database-backups

I am trying to run a for loop for a backup system and inside that i want to run a SP that will loop. Below is the code that does not work for me..

Any ideas please?

```
Dim TotalTables As Integer
Dim i As Integer

TotalTables = 10
  For i = 1 To TotalTables
 objDL.BackupTables(220, i, 001) ' (This is a method from the DL and the 3 parameters are integars)
 Next
```

I tried the SP and it works perfectly in SQLServer

Comment: Does it throw an error or just not do what you expect?

Comment: How does it not work? Does it throw an exception? Does it simply not perform the backup?

Comment: it gives an error of   Message "Invalid object name 'Backup.dbo.AskResponse220_220'." - is it possible this is happening because i have dynamic SQL in my SP?

Comment: i did more debugging and i think the loop is not working because i have a dynamic SQL in my SP therefore it maybe cannot read it well. Any suggestions on how i can make the SP work pleasE?

Comment: You need to post the stored proc. The responders on StackOverflow are talented but not psychic.

Answer (score 0):

Third parameter is bad, should be:

```
objDL.BackupTables(220, i, 1)
```

Comment: yes thats not a problem...i am actually using other values. these were only for examples

do you know what the actual issue might be?

Comment: If you give us your DL code - it might help. What exception it throws?

Comment: i did more debugging and i think the loop is not working because i have a dynamic SQL in my SP therefore it maybe cannot read it well. Any suggestions on how i can make the SP work pleasE?